# WSUS PostInstall Document Moved

Tags: windows-server-2019, wsus

Trying to install WSUS on my Windows Server 2019. After installing the role I am doing the `postinstall` and it is failing and giving this error.

```
2023-10-06 13:34:30.092 UTC Info    WsusService.15  ContentSyncAgent.Download   Item: 7b43518c-cbad-401f-9716-eaa2b76a2a96 has been submitted to BITS for Download 
2023-10-06 13:34:30.113 UTC Info    WsusService.15  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ContentSyncAgent found no more Jobs, going to Sleep for BITS Notifications 
2023-10-06 13:34:30.120 UTC Info    WsusService.15  ContentSyncAgent.WakeUpWorkerThreadProc ContentSyncAgent found no more Jobs, going to Sleep for BITS Notifications 
2023-10-06 13:34:30.652 UTC Info    WsusService.9   ThreadEntry ThreadHelper.ThreadStart 
2023-10-06 13:34:30.652 UTC Warning WsusService.9   DBConnection.OnReceivingInfoMessage  The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is used. 
2023-10-06 13:34:30.872 UTC Error   WsusService.9   SusService.ValidateServerCertificate    Find certificate problem. Error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.EventSystem.SusService.ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Callback(Object state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Invoke(Object request, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback, ProtocolToken& alertToken)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken& alertToken)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)    at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()    at System.Net.Connection.CompleteConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest request)    at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)    at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean onSubmitThread, HttpWebRequest request, TriState needReConnect)    at System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean forcedsubmit)    at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, String connName)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtClients.CheckSelfUpdate(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtClients.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:31.129 UTC Error   WsusService.9   HmtWebServices.CheckReportingWebService Reporting WebService WebException:System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message: -- <head><title>Document Moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://SERVER/reportingwebservice/reportingwebservice.asmx">here</a></body> --.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Reporting.WebService.Ping(Int32 pingLevel)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckReportingWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckReportingWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.007 UTC Error   WsusService.9   HmtWebServices.CheckApiRemotingWebServiceImpl   ApiRemoting WebService WebException:System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message: -- <head><title>Document Moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://SERVER/ApiRemoting30/WebService.asmx">here</a></body> --.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.ApiRemoting.Ping(Int32 pingLevel)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckApiRemotingWebServiceImpl(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger, Int32 retryNumber)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckApiRemotingWebServiceImpl(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger, Int32 retryNumber)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.014 UTC Info    WsusService.9   SusEventDispatcher.RegisterEventHandler RegisterEventHandler called for NotificationEventName: ConfigurationChange 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.131 UTC Error   WsusService.9   HmtWebServices.CheckServerSyncWebService    ServerSync WebService WebException:System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message: -- <head><title>Document Moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://SERVER/ServerSyncWebService/serversyncwebservice.asmx">here</a></body> --.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSyncWebServices.ServerSync.ServerSyncProxy.Ping(Int32 pingLevel)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckServerSyncWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckServerSyncWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.239 UTC Error   WsusService.9   HmtWebServices.CheckClientWebService    Client WebService WebException:System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message: -- <head><title>Document Moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://SERVER/ClientWebService/Client.asmx">here</a></body> --.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.ClientWebService.Client.Ping(Int32 pingLevel)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckClientWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckClientWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.300 UTC Error   WsusService.9   HmtWebServices.CheckSimpleAuthWebService    SimpleAuth WebService WebException:System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message: -- <head><title>Document Moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://SERVER/SimpleAuthWebService/SimpleAuth.asmx">here</a></body> --.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.SimpleAuthWebService.SimpleAuth.Ping(Int32 pingLevel)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckSimpleAuthWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckSimpleAuthWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.362 UTC Error   WsusService.9   HmtWebServices.CheckDssAuthWebService   DssAuth WebService WebException:System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message: -- <head><title>Document Moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://SERVER/DssAuthWebService/DssAuthWebService.asmx">here</a></body> --.    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DssAuthWebService.DssAuthWebService.Ping(Int32 pingLevel)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckDssAuthWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckDssAuthWebService(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.367 UTC Error   WsusService.9   SusService.ValidateServerCertificate    Find certificate problem. Error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.EventSystem.SusService.ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.Invoke(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Callback(Object state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback.Invoke(Object request, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback, ProtocolToken& alertToken)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken& alertToken)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)    at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()    at System.Net.Connection.CompleteConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest request)    at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)    at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean onSubmitThread, HttpWebRequest request, TriState needReConnect)    at System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean forcedsubmit)    at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, String connName)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckContentDirWebAccess(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.ExecuteSubtask(HealthMonitoringSubtask subtask, EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringTasks.Execute(EventLoggingType type)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.Execute(Boolean waitIfNecessary, EventLoggingType loggingType)    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HealthMonitoringThreadManager.PeriodicTask()    at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.PeriodicTaskExecuter.ThreadStart()    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() 
2023-10-06 13:34:32.368 UTC Warning WsusService.9   ServerCertificateValidator.VerifyServerCertificate  The server certificate validation failed because of an SSL policy error: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
```

Looking at the SoftwareDistribution.log is showing during post install it is complaining that the

- reportingwebservices.asmx
- WebService.asmx
- serversuncwebservice.asmx
- Client.asmx
- SimpleAuth.asmx
- dssauthwebservices.asmx

These all were moved. Not sure why it says it moved. It's not moved though. I am confused as to what it is say.

I don't understand where it thinks the files moved to. How do I get my WSUS to complete `postinstall`?

Comment: A rather important clarification: is `SERVER.DOMAIN.NET` exactly what it says in the error message, or are you using that as a substitution for your own domain?

Comment: @tsc_chazz its a place holder for my network.